# Getting a list of ImageNet leaf nodes

Tags: java, wordnet

I want to use the [ImageNet dataset](http://www.image-net.org/) in order to create a list of picturable nouns from its leaf nodes.  There is a small list of 200 picturable nouns [here](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBasic_English_picture_wordlist), but I'm hoping to scale it so that I can detect a larger number of picturable nouns in my project.

How can I get a list of all the leaf nodes in ImageNet?

Comment: You're going to need a good web scrapper

Comment: Are you after the *images*, or a list of Wordnet synsets that have a corresponding entry in ImageNet?